# libgit2sharp remove remote branch

Tags: c#, git, libgit2sharp

I want to delete a branch locally and remote. 
My code:

```
using (var repository = new Repository(path))
{
    var remote = repository.Network.Remotes["origin"];
    var options = new PushOptions();
    var credentials = options.CredentialsProvider = GetUserCredentialsProvider();
    options.CredentialsProvider = credentials;
    string pushRefSpec = @"refs/heads/:{0}".FormatWith(branch);
    repository.Network.Push(remote, pushRefSpec);
    repository.Branches.Remove(repository.Branches[branch]);
}
```

But I get the 401 error ("Unauthorized").
And it's because of the presence of the ":" in the name of the branch.

But I read that they are necessary, because of they are like "--delete" in native git.

Thanks for any helps!

Comment: Have you tried with just `repository.Network.Push(remote, ":branchname");`?

Comment: yes. the same result...

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same thing, but I always get errors (not related to authentication), even with the things posted in the answers. Did you manage to do this?

Answer (score 3):

This is failing with a 401 Unauthorized error because it is unauthorized.  To fix this error, you just need to pass the `options` containing your credentials to the `Push()` method:

```
repository.Network.Push(remote, pushRefSpec, options)
```

That fixed this problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

I just figured out the solution from the libgit2 sourcecode.

```
repository.Network.Push(origin, "+:/refs/heads/to-remove-branch")
```

The part `+:/refs/heads/to-remove-branch` of the refspec specifies that the remove command is forced, else just use `:/refs/heads/to-remove-branch`

Source: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/master/tests/online/push.c

Comment: This gives me an error: `not a valid reference 'branch-name'`. The branch exists, so I have no idea why it fails like that...

Comment: Or an error `invalid refspec +:/refs/heads/branch-name`.

Comment: OK, removing the first slash did it for me: `repository.Network.Push(origin, "+:refs/heads/to-remove-branch", pushOptions);`