# Delete Remote Tag with libgit2sharp

Tags: c#, git, libgit2sharp

I've been unsuccessfully trying to delete a remote tag in git using `libgit2sharp` (v0.24.0). I followed https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/466, but neither of the two recommendations are working for me.

I also came across a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34307963/libgit2sharp-remove-remote-branch/35763696) on deleting a remote branch, however, this did not work either.

I have a simple wrapper around the `libgit2sharp` library and I'm using `NUnit` to execute the `DeleteTagRemote` method.

Here is the wrapper code:

```
public void DeleteTagRemote(string tagName)
{
    using (var repo = new Repository(repoPath))
    {
        var tag = repo.Tags[tagName];
        var remote = repo.Network.Remotes["origin"];

        repo.Network.Push(remote, pushRefSpec: ":" + tag.FriendlyName);
    }
}
```

This results in `LibGit2Sharp.LibGit2SharpException: 'not a valid reference 'TestTag_v0.1''` on the push method.

If I try the other option with `objectish: null, destinationSpec: "my-branch"`, I get

```
System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: objectish'
```

Finally, if I try `repo.Network.Push(remote, ":" + tag.CanonicalName);`, I get

```
LibGit2Sharp.LibGit2SharpException: 'failed to rename lockfile to '*.idx': The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

I have gotten committing, creating a tag, pushing both the commit and tag to the remote, and deleting a local tag to work. Not sure what I'm missing with this one.

Comment: It seems the library is taken by other process. Don´t you have to dispose somewhere in your code?